# What is Metapost/Metafont and how can I get started using it?

Tags: metapost, metafont

Inspired by [Why Metapost discrimination?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/), I'd like to come to know Metapost *far* better than I do now.  All I really know is that Metapost is a language for describing graphics, and Metafont is used specifically for describing fonts.

So what is Metapost/Metafont?

- do Metafont/Metapost have similar syntax, as the names would suggest?
- are the tools to work with and compile them included in the popular TeX distributions?
- is there anything like a 'Hello World' for these systems?  (Various examples with Metapost can be found throughout the site, but not so much Metafont, it seems.)
- can pdfTeX use fonts created with Metafont without too much hassle?
- (same for Metapost, but it would seem that the multiple examples on this site speak for themselves)

Comment: For starters, `texdoc mpman` and `texdoc metafont`. For more fun with `metapost`, I find [this](http://contextgarden.net/MetaFun) and [this](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) really helpful.

Comment: `No documentation for metafont` under MikTeX---that doesn't bode well for point #2 :(

Comment: Related: [pgf/tikz vs metapost](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34523). Also [Why does anyone prefer Metapost?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81902)

Comment: `texdoc mf` is for METAFONT, btw., but it's basically a `man` page.

Comment: Check out `texdoc asymptote`, if you have TeXLive.

Comment: The documentation of Metafont is Knuth's "The METAFONTbook". Yes, `pdftex` can use MF created fonts, but they are bitmap.

Comment: With TeX Live, `texdoc mf` produces the woven sources for METAFONT,  so TeX Live at least produces a valuable resource.

Comment: With LuaTeX you can use MetaPost as an environment; no need for running an external program.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. METAFONT was designed by Knuth to be a companion of TeX. Its job is to produce fonts from "mathematically described" shapes. The output of METAFONT is a collection of bitmapped glyphs; by setting suitable parameters, if the description of the characters is careful, the output can be adjusted to suit any particular printing device (for instance resolution is very important, but it's not the unique aspect to take care of).
2. Metapost is a program directly derived from METAFONT; it was originally written by John Hobby, who made valuable contributions to METAFONT. So, yes, their syntax is similar: the language is actually the same, but Metapost adds several primitives and also data types (RGB and CMYK colors are respectively triples and quadruples that aren't used in METAFONT). Conversely, some of the features of METAFONT are meaningless in Metapost
3. Metapost's output is a simple form of Postscript, and this is the main difference between the two programs: Metapost's output is vector graphics, while METAFONT only outputs rasters.
4. Metapost can interface with TeX to get character metrics and include type in its output. This is not possible in METAFONT (well, there are some TUGboat papers describing clever usage of METAFONT).
5. Fonts created by METAFONT are usable with `pdftex`: all that's possible in Knuth TeX is possible also with `pdftex`. However, the fonts are bitmap, so high resolution versions of them have to be generated if one wants good output; `pdftex` has a couple of primitives for this: `\pdfpkresolution` and `\pdfpkmode` that are used for generating on demand bitmaps from the sources.
6. The output of Metapost, being (Encapsulated) Postscript, can be directly included with `latex`; but, since it uses a restricted set of Postscript functions, it can also be included in `pdflatex` via a set of TeX macros originally written for ConTeXt.
7. A "Hello world" for METAFONT can be found in the METAFONTbook, but it's not really as simple as a similar test document for (La)TeX.
8. A "Hello world" for Metapost can be written "easily". Write the following `hello.mp` document:

   ```
   prologues:=3;                % include all fonts
   outputtemplate:="%j-%c.mps"; % output file will be hello-1.mps
   beginfig(1);
   draw(0,0)--(3cm,0)--(3cm,3cm)--(0,3cm)--cycle;
   label(btex Hello world! etex, (1.5cm,1.5cm));
   endfig;
   end.
   ```

   Run `mpost hello` and then `epstopdf hello-1.mps` to get `hello-1.pdf` for previewing

   [image]

The complete documentation of Metapost is available in the TeX distributions (for TeX Live do `texdoc metapost`).

Answer (score 24):

An intuitive visual overview - http://www.metaflop.com/modulator - make sure to turn on anatomy.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

To expand upon Herbert's comment and as an adjunct to egreg's, here's a code snippet which will allow one to directly process `MetaPost` code within LuaLaTeX, no need for external tools, Thanks in part to [`luamplib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf), a package/support interface for the `mplib` Lua library, an embedded version of MetaPost:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
label ("Insert MP code here", (10,10));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just another reason I should start using LuaTeX... thanks!

Comment: Will the label use the document fonts? In ConTeXt, you have to use `btex text etex` to use document fonts in metapost labels.

Comment: Apparently one can use the default `MP` command for this, e.g., defaultfont := "ptmr8r"; as Taco Hoekwater pointed out to me on the mailing list.

Comment: @Aditya: starting from recent versions of luamplib you can indeed use the `btex … etex` flags to use the same fonts as in the rest of your LuaLaTeX document. You can even use the more flexible `textext("…")` macro much (much similar to the `textext`macro of Metafun), thus allowing loop constructs on your labels for instance.

Comment: @fpast: Thanks for the update. This is great news.